# JSON Stringify ignore key in nested object?

Tags: javascript, json

My `Routine` Object looks like this:

```
export class Routine {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    exercises: RoutineExercise[];
}
```

My `RoutineExercise` Object looks like this:

```
export class RoutineExercise {

    id: string;
    presetKey: string;
    preset: Preset;
}
```

I need to transform a `Routine` Object into a JSON object, but I need to exclude the `preset` Object from every `RoutineExercise`

So I need to do something like this:

```
function replacer(key, value) {
    if (key === "preset") { return undefined; }
}

const jsonString = JSON.stringify(routine, replacer);
console.log(JSON.parse(jsonString));
```

But it doesn't exclude my presets. Probably because the `preset` key is nested in the `exercise` key.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Your `replacer` function should return the value when you need to *keep* it, so use this: `if (key !== "preset") return value;` The other case is `undefined`, but that is the default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your replacer function is not correct. It needs to return the value whenever you want to include the key/value in the JSON. Your code makes it only return `undefined` whatever the key/value.

So use this one:

```
function replacer(key, value) {
    if (key !== "preset") { return value; }
}
```

Or alternatively, you could test for the type of the value:

```
function replacer(key, value) {
    if (!(value instanceof Preset)) { return value; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Delete the key on a copy of the objecrt before stringifying the object to get your result. You can create some sort of function that deletes a key from an object if it exists.

```js
var obj = {
    id: '1',
    presetKey: 'abc',
    preset: 'preset',
}

function filterPreset(obj, key) {
  if (typeof obj === 'object' && obj[key]) {
    var copy = Object.assign({}, obj);
    delete copy[key];
    return copy;
  }
  return obj;
}

console.log('result', JSON.stringify(filterPreset(obj, 'preset')));
console.log('no mutation', obj);
```

Comment: Nope, it creates a copy.

Comment: Would need to be recursive for it to deal with nested objects.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the [... (spread operator)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to deconstruct the object by key and use the rest object which doesn't contain the `preset` key.**

```js
const data = {
    id: '1234',
    presetKey: 'xyz',
    preset: 'customPreset'
};

const { preset, ...rest } = data;

console.log(rest);
```